# window.onbeforeunload not always firing?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My application relies on being able to set a user Online/Offline state.

I have solved this by using the window.onbeforeunload to see when the user leaves a page.

The problem is that the below code does not always get executed and is therefore still saying that some people are online when they have left the page.

This is my current code:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (event) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: './changeStatus.php?cid=' + ccID + '&status=0',
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {},
        error: function (e) {
            //console.log(e);
        }
    });
    return;
};
```

Any ideas how i can force this to *always* get executed? (On all browsers)

Comment: It should be supported in all major browsers. When exactly is it not firing ?

Comment: Sometimes in IE it seems

Comment: IE introduced this, and it's supported since IE4 as far as I know? You'll need to add some more detail on the cases where it's not firing. On the other hand, in IE the problem usually is that the ajax function won't be fast enough to send the request before the page is closed, even if you try to delay it by disabling cache (which does'nt work btw.)

Comment: Ah yea, the problem is probably that its not fast enough. How could i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The script is probably always executed when the page closes, but that doesn't mean that it always succeeds in calling the server.

If for example the user disconnects the internet connection before closing the page, the script can't send anything to the server. You simply can't rely on getting a call from the browser every time the page is closed.

You can keep track on the server when the user was last heard of, so that you can set the user as offline when he hasn't requested any pages for a while. Another alternative is to frequently send a request to the server as long as the user is on the page, and when the requests stop coming, the server knows that the user has gone away.